# How to get Sum from List in another List as a property with linq

Tags: c#, linq

My classes are like below.

```
public class ModelMMaster
{
    public string OrderID { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public List<ModelDetail> _detail { get; set; }
}
public class ModelDetail
{
    public string SKUCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

And I have an order list like

```
List<ModelMMaster> _listMaster = new List<ModelMMaster>
```

I want to calculate `Sum(Quantity * Price)` with LINQ, over `_listMaster`.

I am stuck at this.

```
double _sum =_listMaster.Where(f => f.IsActive == true).Select(f => f._detail)......
```

How can i calculate Sum(Quantity * Price) from _listMaster  with LINQ?

Comment: Perhaps something like this: `_listMaster.Where(x => x.IsActive).SelectMany(x => x._detail).Sum(x => x.Quantity * x.Price);`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve it couple of ways

**Option 1**

```
double _sum =_listMaster.Where(f => f.IsActive)
                         .Sum(x=>x._detail.Sum(c=>c.Price * c.Quantity));
```

**Option 2**

```
double _sum =_listMaster.Where(f => f.IsActive)
                        .Aggregate(0d,(result,item)=>result + item._detail.Sum(x=>x.Price * x.Quantity));
```

**Option 3**

```
double _sum =_listMaster.Where(f => f.IsActive)
                        .SelectMany(x=>x._detail)
                        .Sum(x=>x.Price * x.Quantity);
```

Comment: You can simplify `Where` lamda to `f=>f.IsActive`. It's shorter and do not allow typo like `f => f.IsActive = true`

Comment: @AleksAndreev true, has updated the answer with same. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

```
        List<ModelMMaster> _listMaster = new List<ModelMMaster>();
        List<ModelDetail> _listDetail = new List<ModelDetail>();

        _listDetail.Add(new ModelDetail { SKUCode = "SKUCode-1", Quantity = 1, Price = 1 });
        _listMaster.Add(new ModelMMaster { OrderID = "OrderID-1", IsActive = true, _detail = _listDetail });

        _listDetail = new List<ModelDetail>();
        _listDetail.Add(new ModelDetail { SKUCode = "SKUCode-2", Quantity = 2, Price = 2 });
        _listDetail.Add(new ModelDetail { SKUCode = "SKUCode-3", Quantity = 3, Price = 3 });
        _listMaster.Add(new ModelMMaster { OrderID = "OrderID-2", IsActive = true, _detail = _listDetail });

        var totalSum = _listMaster.Where(t=>t.IsActive).SelectMany(t => t._detail).Sum(t => t.Quantity * t.Price);
```